# Deleting records on PHP/Oracle not working

Tags: php, oracle

This is the part of my application where i have the issue:

https://github.com/ashcrimson/newcyc/tree/master/pages/mantenedores/monedas/monedasList

In model.php at line 33 i have this:

```
public function delete($id): self{
    $sql = $this->pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM MONEDA WHERE CODIGO = :id");
    $sql->execute(["id", $id]);
}
```

In view.php at line 117 i've got the form that should delete the record on the database:

```
<?php if(!$monedas["ELIMINADO"]) { ?>
<a href="<?=base("/monedas/new?id=").$monedas["CODIGO"];?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-pencil-alt"></i> Editar</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-target="#deleteModal<?= $monedas["CODIGO"]; ?>" data-toggle="modal"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i> Eliminar</a>

<!-- modal starts -->
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal<?= $monedas["CODIGO"]; ?>">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="<?=base("/monedas/delete?id=").$monedas["CODIGO"];?>" >
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title"> Borrar <?= $monedas["NOMBRE"]; ?> </h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Continuar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 
<!-- modal ends -->
<?php
}else{
?>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" data-target="#restoreModal<?= $monedas["CODIGO"]; ?>" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-up"></i> Restaurar</a>
```

I don't get why it isn't working. Maybe is because of a bad route?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be more specific than "not working". Are you getting an error message? Are you seeing unexpected results? Try to simplify the code to a [mcve] - this will help you narrow down where the problem is, and help others help you explain it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code in execute is wrong!  Try using:

```
$sql->execute([':id' => $id]);
```

You should put value in your :id

or you can use ? instead of :

```
$sql = $this->pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM MONEDA WHERE CODIGO = ? ");
$sql->execute([$id]);
```